# Unwrap the return type of a tuple of functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a function that accepts a tuple of functions and returns a tuple of those functions' results.

Each function is a `ParseItemFunction`, where input is a Uint8Array and the result may be an error (string) or the ResultType:

```
type ParseItemFunction<ResultType> = (input: Uint8Array) => ResultType | string;
```

A `parseEach` function accepts an input and a list of these functions to perform in series, and it returns either an array of the results or the first error encountered:

```
const parseEach = <FunctionList extends ParseItemFunction<any>[]>(
  input: Uint8Array,
  functions: FunctionList
) => { /* ... */ };

const parseString: ParseItemFunction<string> = (input) => { /* ... */ };
const parseNumber: ParseItemFunction<number> = (input) => { /* ... */ };
const parseBoolean: ParseItemFunction<boolean> = (input) => { /* ... */ };

declare const input: Uint8Array;
const results = parseEach(input, [parseString, parseNumber, parseString, parseBoolean]);
// expected typeof `results`: string | [string, number, string, boolean]
```

How can the return type of `parseEach` be specified to "unwrap" the functions within `FunctionList` while maintaining the order of the returned tuple?

Thanks!

Edit:

After some experimenting, I seem to have a solution:

```
type ExtractResults<T extends readonly ParseItemFunction <unknown>[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ParseItemFunction <infer V> ? V : never;
};
```

But I had to change the signature of `parseEach` to make `functions` a rest argument (to prevent TypeScript from assuming the output may be an array of any length/order of result types):

```
const parseEach = <FunctionList extends ParseItemFunction<any>[]>(
  input: Uint8Array,
  ...functions: FunctionList
): string | ExtractResults<FunctionList> => { /* ... */ };
```

Is there another way to explicitly indicate to TypeScript that `functions` must be a tuple here (without making it a rest argument)?

Comment: What is `ReadResult`?

Comment: @tom10271 ah, that was a typo left over while writing the question. I just removed it, thanks.

Comment: It seems you've changed the scope of your question...  my suggestion here would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N91zMN), using a variadic tuple type for `functions` to give the compiler a hint that you want a tuple there... but nothing will stop you from passing in an array whose order has already been forgotten, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM4EbN).  So your own solution seems to answer your original question, but the variadic tuple type might answer your new version.  Which one, if any, do you want to see written up?